# Sorting undistinguishable balls - $l$-many in one slot - check my proof

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-explanation, balls-in-bins

> We have $n$ different slots und $k$-many undistinguishable balls. We sort the balls into the slots. What is the probability that $l$-many balls, where $l\leq k$, will land in a predetermined slot $\hat{\omega}$?

My solution:

I will try to model it as a Laplace Experiment. So my sample space contains tuples where each entry of the tuple represents the slot of a ball:

$\Omega:=\{(\omega_1, \omega_2, ..., \omega_k):$ where each $\omega_i$ is one slot out of the $n$-many slots $\}$. So $|\Omega|= n^k$. Now I simply count all the ways I can arrange $l$-many $\hat{\omega}$, where $\hat{\omega}$ is the predetermined slot. Those possibilities sum up to: ${k \choose l}$. Further, I count the ways I can fill the remaining $n-1$ slots with $k-l$ balls: $(n-1)^{k-l}.$ Hence, the probability is:
$$\frac{(n-1)^{k-l} {k \choose l}}{n^k}.$$

Maybe this is a really easy question but right now I am so confused by all those combinatoric problems and how to approach them correctly as I don't trust my solution. What do you think?

Comment: So, why would you pick $\ell$ balls from $k$ if all of them look exactly the same? Also, why $|\Omega|=n^k$ if, again, there is no order in the balls.

Comment: I want to transform this problem into a Laplace experiment. If I attach a number to each ball then each tuple of slots $(\omega_1, \omega_2,..., \omega_k)$ has the same probability. I thought this would be easier to approach this problem. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The problem with that is that when you put a number to the ball, they become distinguishable.

Comment: But why is this a problem? I thought it would be legit to make the balls distinguishable because you divide by $n^k$. I have seen other problems with undistinguishable balls where we did the same. If you don't do it this way then you have no order within the tuple anymore. How else would you then assign a probability to a set of slots $\{\omega_1, \omega_2, ..., \omega_k\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers your question in the comments. You are interested in knowing how many balls are in each slot. Let $$\Omega = \{(\omega _1,\cdots ,\omega _n):\sum _{i=1}^n \omega _i=k\},$$
where $\omega _i$ is the number of balls in the $i-$th slot, in this way you are not taking about putting labels in the balls. This, by stars and bars, we have $$|\Omega|=\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}.$$ Now, you know that one of the slots, say $\omega _n$, is filled with $\ell$ balls, then now you are interested in $$X=\{(\omega _1,\cdots ,\omega _{n-1}):\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\omega _i=k-\ell\},$$ this by stars and bars is $$|X|=\binom{k-\ell +n-2}{n-2}$$ and so the probability is the quotient.
To illustrate the confusion, let $n=k=2,\ell =1.$ and let the second slot be the one we want to have $1$ ball. So we have these possible scenarios: (2,0),(1,1),(0,2) and just the one in the middle is valid. This gives $1/3$ of probability. Your formula gives $1/2$.

Comment: Does it mean that my original approach is wrong? I understand why I have to use "stars and bars" but I don't understand why I cannot simply label the balls and do it the way like I did in my original post?

Comment: Because when you labelled them they stop being indistinguishable and the quotient will not take care of it because the way you put the balls is not uniform. I edited to put an example.

Comment: Thanks for your example this makes it a bit clearer to me. However, I am wondering if I can also solve this problem if I label each ball?

Comment: Nop, you can not(or i do not see how directly) because the distribution is not uniform in the sense that each unlabelled class does not contain the same number of labelled elements. So like in the example the unlabelled class (1,1) corresponds to (2,1) and (1,2) in your case. but $(2,0)$ corresponds just to (12,0). You can labelled things and try to take the labelling away iff you know the classes have the same number of elements. Let me know if you want me to say this better in the answer.

Comment: Hmm I think I haven't fully understood it yet but I think I should sleep on it.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with the following issue concerning the answer you provided. Why did you calculate the probability by $\frac{|X|}{|\Omega|}$? I thought that this only is legit when all elements in $\Omega$ are equally probable. However, I don't quite understand why this should be the case if the sample space is defined as you did. As far as I understood your example, where  $n=k=2$, it is true that we have only three outcomes/elements $(2,0), (1,1), (0,2)$ **but** the outcome $(1,1)$ is more likely than the other two, isn't it? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Because is the number of events that you want over all possible events. All the elements in $\Omega$ are equiprobable all elements count just one. Why is that $(1,1)$ is more probable? Has the same probability of the other 2. all of them have probability $1/3$.

Comment: It's essentially because of what you pointed out when you said that $(1,1)$ corresponds to $(2,1)$ **and** $(1,2)$ in my case. Moreover, I came across different posts where they explicitly warned to use the "stars and bars" method to calculate probabilities. I think this post they explained it very well. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1481937/579544 What do you think?

Comment: I was pointing this out because you asked how to do it correctly by labeling the balls. We cant because they are not uniform as i said and as the link you put told us. The statement of your original problem is very clear as it is indistinguishable balls and so the correct way to do it is not labeling them.

Comment: hm to me it makes no sense that when you have 2 balls and 2 bins that landing both balls in one bin is as equally probable as each ball lands in a different bin. If you throw for example two undistinguishable dice then the probability of getting two 6 is still $\frac{1}{36}$ and not $\frac{1}{{6+2-1\choose 2}}$. I am so confused about this because in lecture we already had similar problems with balls and bins and we always labelled them to make each event equally probable. As far as I understood the link it exactly tells us that we shouldn't use stars and bars when calculating the probability.

Comment: The link tells you that if you are treating your "sorting" as one by one independently then is wrong. In your original problem it does not say that we are doing the process one by one. The way is written i assume that you throw all the balls at the same time and magically they appear in the boxes. The problem changes drastically if you drop them one by one.(In that case your solution is correct because you are labeling as the time you throw the ball)

Comment: I think my problem was that I had a fundamental misconception of balls being 
indistinguishable and labelled balls. If I label them then it's, as you  pointed out, a completely different setting/experiment. Thanks for your remarks :)